# I have gotten the response below from a http post request.I am having a hard time extracting the "message" from the body

Tags: java, angular, rest, http, http-post

The message looks like this:
Specifically_body:"{"timestamp":1500492972729,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.RuntimeException","message":"Username already exist","path":"/register"}"

```
this.userService.create(this.model)
        .map((response: Response) =>{
          const data = response.json();
          const extractedChars = data.results;
          const chars = extractedChars.map((char) =>{
            return { message: char.message}
          });
          return chars;
        })
        .subscribe(

            (data) => {
              console.log(data);
                this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            },
            (error) => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            }
            );
```

[Image of response error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQjgR.png)

Comment: "I'm having a hard time" doesn't really explain what problems you're having.

Comment: You can use response.message to get the message.

Comment: for example I am trying to get "Username already exist" from my response.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for your response. As you can see, this is my first time coming on here. I have provided code, picture, http response, and also quoted a part of the response I was trying to retrieve from the response. I see you have a high reputation here and I guess that's why explains your attitude to newcomers. I am sorry if couldn't understand "I'm having a hard time"

Comment: Your original post didn't include much information. When posting, provide as much information as necessary about what you're doing, what you've tried etc. we're not mind readers so the better your question, the better chance you have of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using json() then using .message to refer to the message. The json() converts it to an object.

```
(error) => {
              const results = error.json();
              this.alertService.error(results.message);
              this.loading = false;
             }
```